# Jquery - Load content to div onclick

Tags: jquery

I have a simple menu with `<ul>`s. Every `<ul>` loads its content into a  on clicking it.
The problem is that if a content was loaded and you click the `<ul>` of that content, the scripts reload that same content, what I want is if the content loaded and you just then press the button to load it again it doesn't load and it stays as it is.
Here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/EPvGf/41/

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#menu').on('click', 'a', function () {
        $('.current').not($(this).closest('li').addClass('current')).removeClass('current');
        // fade out all open subcontents
        $('.pbox:visible').hide(600);
        // fade in new selected subcontent
        $('.pbox[id=' + $(this).attr('data-id') + ']').show(600);
    }).find('a:first').click();
});
```

To understand what I'm talking about open the jsfiddle URL you can see "First div" is loaded, try to press "Description" the jquery code loads "First div" again and that isn't what I want

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#" data-id="div1">Description</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-id="div2">Shipping and payment</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-id="div3">Returns</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-id="div4">Feedback</a></li>
</ul><br><br>
<div class="pbox" id="div1">First Div</div>
<div class="pbox" id="div2">Second Div</div>
<div class="pbox" id="div3">Third Div</div>
<div class="pbox" id="div4">Fourth Div</div>
```

And

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.pbox').hide();

    var $mnu = $('#menu').on('click', 'a', function () {
        var $this = $(this), $li = $(this).closest('li');
        if($li.is('.current')){
            return;
        }
        $li.addClass('current');

        $mnu.find('.current').not($li).removeClass('current');
        // fade out all open subcontents
        $('.pbox:visible').hide(600);
        // fade in new selected subcontent
        $('#' + $this.data('id')).show(600);
    });

    $mnu.find('a:first').click();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nySNh/)

Comment: Sorry but first time you enter the URL it loads the whole divs but I want it to loads only the default one that's "First div" so it's not really what I want

Comment: witch solution is the better, yours or the one that Spokey gave me?

Comment: @user2401856 use the one spokey gave, it is cleaner but do not use the class `loaded` you have `current` class already, so use that

Answer (score 2):

Actually the only thing you need to do is add `li:not(.current) a` to your `dynamic selector` and and remove the class from the first `li` (otherwise the trigger click won't work)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#menu').on('click', 'li:not(.current) a', function () {
    $('.current').not($(this).closest('li').addClass('current')).removeClass('current');
    // fade out all open subcontents
    $('.pbox:visible').hide(600);
    // fade in new selected subcontent
    $('.pbox[id=' + $(this).attr('data-id') + ']').show(600);
}).find('a:first').click();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/EPvGf/51/)

Comment: Works perfect, thank you, I will upvote but one question.. what is the better solution the one you gave or the one the man up you gave me?

Comment: there is not need to add the class `loaded` since there is already a class `current`. you can use that

Comment: @ArunPJohny yes I was about to change that now. I did not see it

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if($(this).closest('li').hasClass('current')) return;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EPvGf/49/

It just adds a `hasClass` check and removes the class `current` from the HTML. This way, when you do `find('a:first').click()`, it adds the `current` class.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to css:

```
.pbox {display: none;}
```

Then edit jq script like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#menu').on('click', 'a', function () {
        $('.pbox').hide(600);
        // fade in new selected subcontent
        $('.pbox[id=' + $(this).attr('data-id') + ']').show(600);
    });
});
```

This should work.
Fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/EPvGf/371/